# Unsure of use of ?? in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using this in my UITableViewController datasource to return the number of sections, as defined by my NSFetchedResultsController.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}
```

I've stumbled across this from samples on Swift and it works, but am unsure what the double ? means/does.

Help appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_123

Comment: Right! Thanks...the nil coalescing operator...wow!  So, shorthand for  a != nil ? a! : b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called the nil coalescing operator, and it is shorthand for the following:

return self.fetchedResultsController.sections != nil ? self.fetchedResultsController.sections! : 0

Comment: It is _sort_ of a shorthand for that, but it has some extra niceness built it. It is a different operator.

Comment: @matt the primary difference is that the conditional expression is only evaluated one time?

Comment: I think the ternary operator is lazy too. But it's a real operator. So for example you can chain them and the right thing happens even without parentheses: `i ?? j ?? k ?? 0` means we try to find the first one that isn't nil and then we give up and use `0`. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the number of sections is not nil, return the count of the sections. Otherwise return 0